# query about data storing in android

Tags: android, database

How can I store data about books like author name, price, category etc in a book shopping android app and retrieve all books with details including corresponding image on selecting a category of book in a activity page?

I want to create stock inventory for my app that contain images with other data and retrieve these data. I'm using eclipse for developing my android app.

Answer (score 1):

This question is really too general to be answered. But this project should give you a good start for what you want: [Shelves](http://code.google.com/p/shelves/).

Once you get going, come back with more specific questions, and don't underestimate the search function and google.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use some light weight database. Some options as below:

1. [**SQLite**](http://www.sqlite.org/): SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine. SQLite is the most widely deployed SQL database engine in the world. The source code for SQLite is in the public domain.
2. [**HSQL**](http://hsqldb.org/): HSQLDB (HyperSQL DataBase) is the leading SQL relational database engine written in Java. It offers a small, fast multithreaded and transactional database engine with in-memory and disk-based tables and supports embedded and server modes. It includes a powerful command line SQL tool and simple GUI query tools.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do that will be by using an `SQLite` database. For a crash course in `SQLite`, go [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sqlite/). As for storing pictures, you should store it in sdcard and save paths to the images in the `SQLite` `database`.